# Calculating confidence score for Entity in NLP Named-entity recognition

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am working on named-entity extraction from documents(pdfs). Each pdf contains set of entities (nearly 16 different type entities)

Here are my steps to build the NLP and ML models:

- `Step 1` : Parsed documents. Got nearly 2 Million tokens (words). Used these words and CBOW method for building word2vec model.
- `Step 2` : By used word2vec model, generated vectors for words in douments.
- `Step 3` : As per the domain, i labeled words(vectors) for training, validation and testing.
- `Step 4` : With labeled data, train the Neural Network model.
- `Step 5`: Once model got build, given testing data (words) to the model. Got 85% accuracy.

Till now everything going good. But problem is in next step. :(

- `Step 6` : Now i want to make entities with confidence score from words which are classified from the trained model.

Neural network model using `SOFTMAX` to classify input. From this model getting score for each word.

But my question is, my entities contains minimum 3 words. How can i calculate confidence score for generated entity.

right now i am using `P(entity) = P(w1)*P(w2)*(w3)`  if entity has three words.

Kindly help me. this approach wont make sense all the time.

suppose, if model predict only two words in entity then entity confidence will be  `P(entity) = P(w1)*P(w2)`.

And if model predict only one word in a entity then `P(entity) = P(w1)`. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not P(entity) = P(w1)+P(w2)+P(w3) ?
if you need a normalized number (0-1) and assuming that P(w) has a 0-1 range make it: P(entity) = (P(w1)+P(w2)+P(w3)) / 3

For a better score, you should calculate the information content of each word. A common word should contribute less: https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-6-S1-S21

Answer (score 0):

Stanford NLP toolkit uses the min(Pi) as P(entity). From my perspective, neither is sound from the mathematical view.